# Questions on addition and multiplication of large integer stored in array. (C programming)

Tags: c

How do I add 2 large numbers (like a thousand digits large) recursively?

I stored the inputs as strings into an array, and I want to add them using a recursive function.

I understand the logic, I just don't understand how do I add them using recursion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I think it's also polite to add that this is homework.

Comment: do you mean add digit to digit and perform carries etc?

Comment: Using recursion to add big numbers is a bad idea, it wastes space on the stack, and is slower than a simple iterative solution. Why do you want to do this recursively, and not iteratively?

Comment: because thats what his homework says to do

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about us doing your homework without you really trying to do anything

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you will have an array of 'digits' for the inputs: `unsigned int a[num_ints], b[num_ints]`

It may be easier for you to use `unsigned char a[num_digits], b[num_digits]` and store the values `0-9` ONLY in each byte. But this is very wasteful on a 32 bit machine.

The easy way would be to make your inputs `a,b` global arrays and simply return carry info recursive function.

Then you could do something like this:

```
void *recursive_op(unsigned char *ptr){
    carry_t *carry_info = recursive_op(ptr-1));
    //do something with the carry_info
}

unsigned char result[num_digits];
unsigned char a[num_digits];
unsigned char b[num_digits];

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    //initialise a and b...
    //memset result to zeros...

    unsigned char *ptr = &result[num_digits-1];
    carry_t *carry_info = recursive_op(ptr);

    //do something to result[0] with your carry_info ptr
}
```

Here I'm assuming a great deal about the endianess of your arry (the most significant 'digit' is at `numdigits-1`, the least significant 'digit' is at `0`) AND I'm assuming you want to operate on the least sig. digits first (ie, right-to-left like how we are taught at school).

I haven't compiled the code or sanity checked it. It's really just an outline.